# Passing $_GET variables to virtual directories via .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` **Rewrite rule** below which works for converting virtual directories to parameters, for example:

`www.example.com/usa/ny/nyc` gets interpreted by PHP as `www.example.com/index.php?path=usa/ny/nyc`.

What I can't seem to figure out is how I would change my `regex` below to handle parameters of the virtual directories themselves. For example, I want:

`www.example.com/usa/ny/nyc/?display=off&settings=none` to be seen by PHP as `www.example.com/index.php?path=usa/ny/nyc&param=display:off,settings:none`.

What makes it extra tricky is that the parameters won't always be those two options I used in the example above, they will change dynamically. Any ideas or suggestions of how to go about accomplishing this?

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_\-/]+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to rewrite the additional parameters in the new format, rather than passing them as additional `_GET` parameters?

Comment: Definitely not! I can display the additional parameters in normal format, I just used that format because I thought it would be less confusing to work with in my PHP script because I'll have to explode() the string anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to pass the query string unmodified, you can use the `[QSA]` (query string append) option like so:

```
RewriteRule /(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can find the documentation for the `QSA` option [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html).  From the docs:

> With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped
>   to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same
>   request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing
>   query string will be discarded.

So, your PHP script will see all the parameters as standard `_$_GET` parameters, rather than needing to do any other modification.

If you would prefer to treat the result more like a typical path element, you can use the following:

```
RewriteRule /(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In the above case, your query string will still be appended, however you will need to handle the path explicitly using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: After implementing the QSA flag, I noticed that when I visit a virtual directory without the trailing slash, it redirects the URL to look like: "localhost:8888/?path=/Application/MAMP/project". Any idea of how to avoid this?

Comment: What would you expect this result to look like instead?

Comment: Ideally, I would expect the restructuring of the virtual directories to be invisible to the user, only looking different when parsed by PHP. For example, whether a user visits "http://localhost:8888/project" or "http://localhost:8888/project/" (with trailing slash), I want the two to produce the same result. Yet, with the QSA flag and no trailing slash, the URL redirects to: "http://localhost:8888/project/?path=Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project"

Comment: Didn't work for me but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521072/using-htaccess-to-pass-directories-to-get-parameters-without-rewriting-url) did