# Using htaccess to pass directories to GET parameters Without rewriting url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to pass (not redirect) something like this:

http://www.example.com/ (with / optional)
passed to the script
http://www.example.com/index.php

http://www.example.com/foo/ (with / optional)
passed to the script
http://www.example.com/index.php?nav=foo

http://www.example.com/foo/bar (with / optional)
passed to the script
http://www.example.com/index.php?nav=foo&subnav=bar

Furthermore I would like to pass the subdomain http://testumgebung.example.com to http://www.example.com/testumgebung.php with the same parameters as above.

I just managed to do the following, but it rewrites the url in the browser bar to the passed location and doesn't leave the url as before:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^testumgebung\.maskesuhren\.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maskesuhren.de/$1/testumgebung.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.html?nav=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*/.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.html?nav=$1&subnav=$2 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get rid of the `R` in the last 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^testumgebung\.maskesuhren\.de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maskesuhren.de/$1/testumgebung.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.html?nav=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*/.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.html?nav=$1&subnav=$2 [L]
```

The `R` in the square brackets tell mod_rewrite to redirect the browser, which changes the URL in the browser's location bar.
.

Comment: You are right, but I have to deal with external resources which are not at example.com/foo/bar/js/bla.js but at example.com/js/bla.js. Any  solutions to circumvent this issue? Another problem I have is that the subdomain testumgebung is redirected to http://www.maskesuhren.de/testumgebung.html but i would like to keep it at testumgebung.maskesuhren.de. Thx for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the order to achive what I wanted

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/?$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ ?nav=$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.*/.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ ?nav=$1&subnav=$2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testumgebung\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ testumgebung.html [L]
```

and to rewrite the html so that the external resources start with a slash.