# regular expression help matching a subdirectory for url rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I need to capture individual sub-directories and assign each of them a reference. The reference order doesn't matter, each reference will be checked individually.
Here is an example url:

- http://test.com/test1/test2/happy-1200/

The URL variables (sub-directories) can also be in any order:

- http://test.com/test1/happy-1200/test2/

here is my regex so far, but it doesn't work.:

```
^(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:[\w.-]+)\/?.*$(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\/){0,12}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:[\w.-]+)?(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+){0,12}\/?
```

If the above one doesn't work, you should do something like this:

```
^(?:\w+:\/\/)?(?:[\w.-]+)?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?\/?
```

Comment: Maybe this one would be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521072/using-htaccess-to-pass-directories-to-get-parameters-without-rewriting-url

Comment: This almost works, it captures the last "directory" in the url it seems, but not the others.

Comment: The problem with the link you sent is it looks they are assuming the order of the sub-directories will always be foo/bar/, even though bar is optional.

Comment: Your second suggestion would work, except iis won't allow me to make the expression long enough to handle 12+ variables.

Comment: You could repeat `(?:(\/[0-9a-zA-Z-]+))?` as many times as you need.

Comment: Or, if it helps, hoy can replace `[0-9a-zA-Z-]` with `[^\/]` which saves you some room.

Comment: Awesome, shortening it with [^\/] worked great. Thank you very much for your help!